# Can I make a transparent fade-in Nested Gradient?

Tags: css, gradient

So a theme I am using has a transparent to full color gradient section that allows for scrolling through the menu with a nice fade out effect.

I am working on modifying this theme and have added a basic top to bottom gradient to the main navigation. Now I am trying to edit the "fade out" piece but when I try to figure out how to fade into a top/bottom gradient with a 90 degree transparent effect my brain starts to hurt.

Here is my top-bottom gradient for the whole menu:
`background-image: linear-gradient(#55b8ff, #daeffd);`

Here is the (currently fading into plain black) code for the "fade out gradient" from the theme:
`background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(10,11,12,0) 0,#0a0b0c);`

Basically I want the 90 degree fade in to fade into a top-bottom gradient so it looks seemless. Something like this:

`background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(10,11,12,0) 0,linear-gradient(#55b8ff, #daeffd));`

But that does not seem to work so maybe there is another way or my syntax is wrong?

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgba(10,11,12,0),transparent),linear-gradient(#55b8ff, #daeffd)` ?

Comment: Hi, thanks I tried this code and it shows a solid piece not gradient. See here: https://imgur.com/LRqvyQb